# Regain ability to use ^C to close backgrounded then (effectively) foregrounded processes

Tags: bash, job-control, sigint, wait

In the interactive console, pressing `^C` on `zenity --info & fg` closes the Zenity window. One can only use `zenity --info & wait` in a script. But `^C` doesn't close the Zenity window in this case. Is there any way to make `wait` behave more like `fg` and make `^C` work?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can do is to trap the `SIGINT` (^C) and kill the background process from the handler:

```
#! /bin/sh
trap 'kill "$!"; exit 1' INT QUIT
zenity --info &
wait
```

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490076/308316) and other similar [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A308316+SIGINT+SIGQUIT+) for an explanation for this behavior.

When calling your script from some shells like `bash` which implement the so-called ["Wait and Cooperative Exit"](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230421/unable-to-stop-a-bash-script-with-ctrlc) for a discussion), the expected way for a program to cleanly exit upon receiving a signal is by resetting the handler and then killing itself with the same signal:

```
#! /bin/sh
termsig(){ trap - "$1"; kill "$!"; kill -s "$1" "$$"; }
trap 'termsig INT' INT
trap 'termsig QUIT' QUIT 
zenity --info &
wait
```

All this is of course quite gross and won't be able to do anything about children processes that `zenity` itself may have spawned, and will have to be adapted for more than one background process. The more obvious solution `(trap - INT; zenity --info) &` will **not** work with the `/bin/sh` from any Debian-derived distros (Ubuntu, etc) or any busybox-based systems.

Another solution would be run your program through a wrapper that allows you to reset the `SIGINT` disposition to default, eg. with `perl`:

```
#! /bin/sh
perl -e '$SIG{INT} = $SIG{QUIT} = "DEFAULT"; exec @ARGV' zenity --info &
wait
```

But if you go that way, you may just as well re-write your whole script in `perl` or `python` ;-)

Comment: Unlike the `ping` from the linked example, this script won't exit with a 0 status upon a signal, so a simple `while ...; .do ... /script || break; done` will do. Committing seppuku (by resetting the handler and re-sending itself the signal) won't help with that anyway and may run into other [issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513516/dash-why-am-i-getting-the-error-syntax-error-eof-in-backquote-substitution-w/513562#513562).

Comment: I've added a seppuku variant too, though I really don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

In a non-interactive `sh`, commands run asynchronously with `&` have their SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals ignored.

That's a POSIX requirement, and goes back to the time when terminal job control (`tcsetpgrp()`...) didn't exist. Today, it generally gets in the way.

Another POSIX requirement and that comes from the same origin is that when a signal was ignored upon shell startup, it cannot be un-ignored with `trap`. Again, nowadays, that's unwanted and annoying behaviour.

`zsh` implements that latter requirement only partly. a `trap - SIGNAL` to restore the default disposition of an ignored `SIGNAL` is ignored, but `trap handler SIGNAL` installs the `handler` for SIGNAL even when that SIGNAL was ignored upon startup, so one can still restore the default disposition if they really want to with `trap : SIGNAL; trap - SIGNAL`.

As long as SIGINT was not ignored in the script (like when the script was run in background), you can do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
(trap - INT QUIT; exec zenity) & wait
```

To restore the default disposition for SIGINT and SIGQUIT.

However, [though POSIX explicitly says it should work](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_11), it doesn't with a few `sh` implementations. In particular, not with `dash` and most other `ash` derivatives, `ksh93`, `bosh` or `yash`. So you may want to change the she-bang to `#! /bin/bash -` or `#! /bin/zsh -` or `#! /bin/mksh -` to make sure you have a POSIX-compliant shell in this instance.

If SIGINT was ignored upon startup of the shell, you'll need to use `zsh` to restore their disposition:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
trap : INT QUIT # noop handler to unignore
trap - INT QUIT # restore default disposition for the shell
(trap - INT QUIT; zenity) & wait
```

Example (here on Linux where the signal dispositions are exposed as bitmaps in `/proc/<pid>/status`):

```
$ sh -c 'grep SigIgn /proc/self/status'
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
$ sh -c 'grep SigIgn /proc/self/status & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000000006 # (1<<(SIGINT-1) | 1<<(SIGQUIT-1))

$ zsh -c '(trap - INT QUIT; exec grep SigIgn /proc/self/status) & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
$ bash -c '(trap - INT QUIT; exec grep SigIgn /proc/self/status) & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
$ mksh -c '(trap - INT QUIT; exec grep SigIgn /proc/self/status) & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000000000

$ dash -c '(trap - INT QUIT; exec grep SigIgn /proc/self/status) & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000000006
$ ksh93 -c '(trap - INT QUIT; exec grep SigIgn /proc/self/status) & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000000006
$ yash -c '(trap - INT QUIT; exec grep SigIgn /proc/self/status) & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000000006
$ bosh -c '(trap - INT QUIT; exec grep SigIgn /proc/self/status) & wait'
SigIgn: 0000000000100006  # also SIGTTIN

$ (bash -c 'grep SigIgn /proc/self/status' & wait)
SigIgn: 0000000000000006
$ (bash -c 'trap - INT QUIT; grep SigIgn /proc/self/status' & wait)
SigIgn: 0000000000000006

$ (zsh -c 'grep SigIgn /proc/self/status' & wait)
SigIgn: 0000000000000002 # not sure why the SIGQUIT was unignored
$ (zsh -c 'trap - INT QUIT; grep SigIgn /proc/self/status' & wait)
SigIgn: 0000000000000002
$ (zsh -c 'trap : INT QUIT; trap - INT QUIT; grep SigIgn /proc/self/status' & wait)
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
```

Comment: Your first example only works with `zsh`, too. Why the `#! /bin/sh` shebang?

Comment: @mosvy, it works with mksh, bash and zsh and should work in POSIX compliant implementations. I've added a note.

Comment: The first sentence should probably be "In a `sh` run without job control enabled (as in a script or subshell), etc". Also, you really should change that shebang to `#! /bin/bash` -- that won't work with the `/bin/sh` from debian, ubuntu, busybox, etc; no matter if "entry to a non-interactive shell" in the standard is interpreted to include subshells or not.